# Extremely simple column manipulation in PROC SQL

Tags: sql, proc, proc-sql

I'm working in PROC SQL (SAS Enterprise Guide) for the first time and struggling to get to grips with some basics.

I have a table that looks like this:

```
Variable_Name   Instance 
Var1            Integer1
Var2            Integer2
Var2            Integer3
...
```

I want to divide every integer in Instance by the same number and create a new column containing the (decimal) answers. For some reason I've found this bizarrely difficult to do.
I'm aware that this is incredibly basic, but I can't find any tutorials that have helped.

Thank you for any insight.

EDIT

Example of a couple of things I've tried:

Creating a third column and using INSERT INTO to manually input numbers, but they're inputted into the next empty rows instead of the first index.

Trying to just find the values and output them, but I kept getting errors that it expected commas instead of semicolons.

I have done other things very unsuccessfully and don't understand enough to explain what went wrong.

Comment: "I've found this bizarrely difficult to do" - sounds like you have at least tried something, so please post it and explain why it didn't work.

Comment: @underscore_d I've had a go at explaining what I've tried...

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Do you really need an SQL solution? Or would a solution using normal SAS code work?

Answer (score 0):

You would just use:

```
proc sql;
    select t.*,
           var1 / 5 as new_var1,
           var2 / 5 as new_var2,
           var3 / 5 as new_var3
    from t;
```

EDIT:

If you have 20 rows with 2 columns, you would just do:

```
proc sql;
    select t.*, instance / 5 as new_instance
    from t;
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without having to define each row? There are 20 rows and doing that for each individual one would be possible but a time sink.

Comment: The posted code says nothing about rows. It is defining the variables (columns).  The query operates on all of the observations (rows).

Answer (score 0):

The Question is slightly confusing - but this might be one of cross pollinating data types

To ensure a decimal result is produced from a calculation using an integer as the first operand, it is probably worth ensuring the integer is supplied as a decimal -

There appear to be several methods for Data Types and casting - but this might help - adjust the FORMAT value according to number of decimal places etc.

```
proc sql;
    select t.*,
           instance / 5 as new_var1  FORMAT=3.1,
           instance / 5 as new_var2  FORMAT=3.1,
           instance / 0.5 as new_var3  FORMAT=3.1
    from t;
```

This Doc looks very useful
https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings16/7540-2016.pdf